# Chrome - Disable file:/// protocol

Tags: google-chrome

Is there a way to disable file:/// protocol in google chrome?

Is there some option, or some switches that can disable this feature?

Please help

Comment: No. There is no switch to do this listed in [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/). It might help if you told us **why** you want to do this ...

Comment: I need to protect my computer from my brothers, I've already disabled access to drives in windows, so they can't open many windows folders etc, but through chrome file:/// protocol they can still see these folders...

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 ultimate

Comment: Even if you managed to do this they could just use a USB strick with a portable version of chrome ... or some other browser.

Comment: Yes, but now I just need to know how to disable file:/// protocol. I can't believe that is there no way to do it...

Answer (score 3):

## You can use an chrome extension to block file://

In the policies force install an extension that redirects all file:// urls to a blocked page. Example code:

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function(tabs){
    if(tabs[0].url.startsWith('file://')) {
         chrome.tabs.update('{blocked page}')
    }
});
```

Remember to replace `blocked page` to match the actual blocked page.

Answer (score 2):

#### Is there a way to disable file:/// protocol in google chrome?

There is no switch to do this listed in the [List of Chromium Command Line Switches](http://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/).

[URLProtocolView v1.15 - View/Enable/Disable URL protocols](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/url_protocol_view.html) from Nirsoft seems to do what you want.

> **Description**
>
> URLProtocolView is a simple utility that displays all URL protocols
>   (for example: ftp:, telnet:, mailto:) that are currently installed on
>   your system. For each URL protocol, the following information is
>   displayed: The protocol name, the protocol description, the
>   command-line that is executed when you type or click the URL, the
>   product name, and the company name.
>
> **This utility also allows you to easily enable/disable the URL protocols.**

Comment: Does it will disable the protocol for all windows users? I need to disable the protocol only for a specific user

Comment: Probably for all users ... :/

Answer (score 1):

Chrome has a policy engine that you can use. The policy to block file browser access from the URL bar is called `URLBlockList` (it might be `URLBlackList` in older versions).

https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=URLBlocklist

Comment: To clarify this, on Windows you need to create a new key named `URLBlocklist` in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome` and add to it a _String value_ (`REG_SZ`) named `1` with the URL to block as value. For every other URL you want to block add another _String value_ named `2`, `3`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

[LeechBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/leechblock-ng/blaaajhemilngeeffpbfkdjjoefldkok?hl=en-US) (a free Chrome extension) can do this.

Open the LeechBlock options page, then click <kbd>Show Advanced Options</kbd> at the bottom of the page. In the "Use regular expression to match URLs to block (overrides list of sites)" box, enter `^file:\/\/\/`. This  will block all URIs beginning with `file:///`.