# How to stop Windows 10 intercepting hyperlinks to the Windows Store?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-10, http, spyware

In Windows 10 when you click certain links to microsoft.com/en-US/store (like [this one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/Apps/Intercept-You/9WZDNCRDJFXM)) in Chrome or any other browser, the "Store" app opens.

Has anyone figured out a way to disable this anti-feature?

I kind of remember experiencing something similar when I tried Windows 8, but I can't seem to find any resources detailing how to do this for either Windows 8 or 10.

**UPDATE**

As I wrote in the [TechNet forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dc13ee9a-d051-4090-a182-4f78a83495fb/stop-intercepting-browser-links-to-the-windows-store?forum=win10itprogeneral), it's all coming back to me now... This is happening because of the `ms-windows-store://` protocol and some javascript on the Windows Store webpages that makes a request to it...

So, I guess I have to just find a way to ad-block this content, disable the protocol in Windows or maybe I'll just disable Javascript for those pages.

Here are some related resources:

- [ZDNet article about ms-windows-store protocol](http://www.zdnet.com/article/cant-shop-for-windows-store-apps-using-chrome-but-is-google-being-evil/)
- [A Firefox bug report regarding the protocol](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=866065)

Comment: If you know the answer, even to your own question, then please post it as an answer. If not this post will remain open and in the unanswered category forever.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't have the answer when I updated the question - just more info. But now I have some working answers, so I'll post them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that works today is to add the following filter to Adblock custom filters in Chrome:

`https://assets.onestore.ms/cdnfiles/*/redirect.min.js`

Blocking that script will not work forever. I'd much rather have a browser setting that disables usage of any protocol outside of the typical http/https/mailto/etc.

Another possible solution is to use [this URL Protocol tool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/url_protocol_view.html) from NirSoft to disable the `ms-windows-store://` protocol, which I found thanks to this [SuperUser question](https://superuser.com/questions/843945/chrome-disable-file-protocol). This seems a little heavy-handed to me and it may break Windows, so I won't be trying this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Run the windows powershell as admin, then type:

```
Get-AppxPackage *windowsstore* | Remove-AppxPackage
```

This will uninstall the store app. Works with most other apps, too, but sadly not with pain in the neck Cortana. If you need it again there's a way to reinstall the build apps. but I can't remember the command.

Comment: Thank you. That is certainly a valid response to this type of behavior from Microsoft, but I'm not trying to remove the entire app store, just the behavior that I described.

Comment: I admit that this is more of a dirty hack then a proper solution. A more restrained solution would be to add the link to any Adblocker.