# Prevent Google Chrome from accessing C:\ or local files

Tags: google-chrome, windows-explorer, blocking

We're trying to block the users from accessing to local files from Chrome.

We've disabled the access from Windows Explorer. However, if the users use Google Chrome, then they can easily type `C:` in the address bar, following which they can access local files. You can see an example below:

[image: Accesing C: from Chorome]

Does anyone know how to block the access?

I've been looking options such as:

- Block the file system
- Configuring the user agent stylesheet, default styles, as well as the main set-up.

I'm looking in the JavaScript to edit it but I haven't found a solution. This image below is what I see, but I don't know the location for the file that gives a style or format to the local directory and I haven't found such a file in the latest Chrome version.

[image: This code]

Comment: The answer was already given a few years ago: the only way to disable this is to use a third party program. Specifically:URLProtocolView . https://superuser.com/questions/843945/chrome-disable-file-protocol

Comment: The file viewer parts are compiled into Chrome and can't be removed.

Comment: You can use the C:  path in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer.  Similar path type are used to launch server sessions. So it is a normal part of browsers.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can stop this. You're best bet is probably to set up a managed version of Chrome, or just block the site, which I'm pretty sure you can do with managed machines. Also, I'm pretty sure that you're some sort of school admin. If so, leave the students some sort of exploit. :)