# Block file://domain opening in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, filesystems, file-permissions, file-sharing, local

When users open any pdf with chrome browser, they can see cnc path and then browse to other user folders. How can I prevent this so they cant open local files via chrome. On so many websites forums no help at all. Much appreciated.

When they click on pdf file and click open with
goes to CNC path
file:///mydomainname

Comment: Does [Chrome - Disable file:/// protocol - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/843945/chrome-disable-file-protocol) answer your question?

Comment: Blocking the path from being viewed in chrome still won't prevent the underlying problem from being exploited. You need access control for your users to prevent them accessing other users data. Whats to stop them from using `ctrl` + `o` to open files in other places?

Comment: Yes you are right and im working on it. 
Does someone know any powershell script to add individual permissions to individual users at same time